# Reading multiple data files in a single array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, file, fortran

I am using fortran 77. I have multiple (say N) data files containing data of same size (say S) each. I want to read all these data files in one single array of size (N*S) into my program. The data files are named in a arranged manner (datafile1.dat, datafile2.dat......datafileN.dat).

Any clues how can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using Fortran 95 notation a possible solution could look like:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: NN = 2
  integer, parameter :: SS = 3
  character(len=128) :: fname
  integer :: data(NN * SS)
  integer :: ii

  do ii = 1, NN
    write(fname, "(A,I0,A)") "datafile", ii, ".dat"
    open(12, file=fname, form="formatted")
    read(12, *) data((ii-1)*SS+1:ii*SS)
    close(12)
  end do
  print *, data

end program test
```

You can easily rewrite it into Fortran 77 notation if needed although most compilers understand Fortran 90/95 already:

```
      program test
      implicit none

      integer NN, SS
      parameter(NN = 2, SS = 3)
      character*128 fname
      integer data(NN * SS)
      integer ii, jj

      do ii = 1, NN
        write(fname, "(A,I0,A)") "datafile", ii, ".dat"
        open(12, file=fname, form="formatted")
        do jj = 1, SS
          read(12, *) data((ii-1)*SS+jj)
        end do
        close(12)
      end do
      print *, data

      end program test
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `implicit none` is not standard FORTRAN77 though it was a widely-implemented extension.  It was anointed in the Fortran 90 standard.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Thanks! I did not know that. Fortunately, I do not have to deal with F77 codes much (any more).

Comment: Nor I, and when I do the first thing I do is insert `implicit none` as you have suggested.